# Хороший-гарний-добрий

Tags: вживання-слів

Слова *хороший-гарний-добрий* є синонімами, але в яких випадках їх доречно використати правильно?

Щодо зовнішньої краси — *гарний*, добротний — *хороший*, риса характеру — *добрий*.

А якщо мова йде про позитивну оцінку? *Хороші* чи *гарні* відгуки? *Добрі*, *хороші* чи *гарні* стосунки?

Comment: [Ось тут](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t3246.html) цікаве обговорення.

Answer (score 2):

Великий тлумачний словник (ВТС) сучасної української мови

> ***[ГАРНИЙ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53395/850511.html)*** 1. Приємний зовнішнім виглядом; який відзначається
>   гармонією барв, ліній і т. ін. || Який має привабливу зовнішність,
>   привабливі риси обличчя. || Приємний для слуху; милозвучний. ||
>   Блискучий, ефектний.
>
> ***2. Який має позитивні якості або властивості, цілком відповідає вимогам, заслуговує схвалення.*** || Який сприяє успіхові, пов'язаний з
>   ним; вдалий. || Про погоду, клімат і т. ін. || Про душевний стан.
>
> ***[ДОБРИЙ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53396/861885.html)*** -а, -е. 1. ***Який доброзичливо, приязно, чуйно ставиться до
>   людей***; доброзичливий; прот. лихий, поганий. || до кого і без додатка.
>   Привітний, лагідний у взаєминах. || у знач. ім. добрий, -рого, ч. Той,
>   хто доброзичливо, приязно, чуйно ставиться до людей. || Який виражає
>   доброту, щирість; сповнений ласки, приязні (про голос, усмішку,
>   обличчя і т. ін.). || Уживається як постійний епітет до сл. люди,
>   хлопці і т. ін. (найчастіше у формі звертання). Добра душа — чуйна,
>   щира, спокійна людина.
>
> 2. ***Для якого характерна взаємна прихильність, симпатія; близький.***
> 3. ***Який приносить добро, задоволення, радість і т. ін.***
>
> ***[ХОРОШИЙ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53413/1013381.html)*** -а, -е.1. ***Який має позитивні якості або властивості***;
>   який своїми якостями цілком відповідає поставленим вимогам; такий, як
>   треба; прот. поганий. || Який заслуговує схвалення: досконалий. ||
>   Схвальний, приємний. || Те саме, що милозвучний. || Гарний, справжній
>   (про життя). || Корисний, потрібний. || Нічим не затьмарений (про
>   настрій, душевний стан і т. ін.); піднесений. || Викликаний приємними
>   почуттями, добрими намірами. || Ясний, тихий, теплий, сонячний (про
>   погоду, пору дня, року і т. ін.).

Отже, ***гарні*** оцінки, ***хороші*** відгуки, ***добрі*** стосунки.

Answer (score 2):

Згідно з сайтом [«ОнлайнКоректор»](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B8/), коли ми говоримо "про особу чи предмет з позитивними якостями або властивостями", то краще вживати прикметник "**добрий**", а коли про зовнішність — "**гарний**". **АЛЕ** врахуйте що:

> Прикметник "**хороший**" в українській мові має значення «який має
>   привабливу зовнішність, гарні риси обличчя; вродливий»: Хороший з
>   лиця, повновидий, рум’янець на всю щоку, з чорними веселими очима, з
>   чорним лискучим усом, він був перший красень на селі… (Панас Мирний)

На сайті [«Как правильно?»](https://kak-pravilno.net/garnij-chi-horoshij-yak-pravilno/) також читаємо, що краще вживати слово «**гарний**» в значенні красивий, вродливий; а слово «**хороший**» щей може вживатися в значенні добрий, добротний.

Згідно з відео-уроком [«Хороший фільм чи гарний?»](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kjZFYCY_4Q) від Олександра Авраменка — **гарним** може бути як і людина, так і якийсь предмет, характер, частини тіла. "**Хороший**" також можна вживати до предметів та людей ("хороший з лиця", "хороша книжка"). Однак, коли говоримо про красу, то краще вживати слово "**гарний**", а коли маємо значення "добрий, добротний" — "**хороший**".

Comment: Коментатори роблять помилку. Не "згідно до чого", а "згідно з чим": треба "згідно з відео"

Comment: @Михайло, цілком згоден. Ви можете запропонувати редагування до відповіді, натиснувши [«improve this answer» чи «edit»](/posts/4532/edit). Якщо редагування буде хороше, то його ухвалять — цим Ви не лише допоможете іншим, але й отримаєте додаткові бали. Дякую!